# Docker images not visible after moving data-root directory

Tags: docker, portainer

After moving my data-root directory to an SD card my new docker data directory is `/mnt/sd/var/lib/docker` and everything is there, but docker/portainer do not see the images, containers, stacks, volumes..nothing

Also I cannot access the `docker` directory in that path and need to change permissions all the time.

I think docker may not have the permissions. Any ideas how to make my data appear again in docker/portainer?

I am changing the persmissions manually using `sudo chmod -R 775 /mnt/sd/var/lib/docker` but it has just a temporary effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this yesterday and found this post and one other; not fully answered. Using information gleaned from [another post](https://forums.docker.com/t/error-starting-container-after-moving-docker-root-directory/64324), I've discovered to complete the solution one needs to update each `config.v2.json` inside each docker ID subdirectory (`/mnt/sd/var/lib/docker/containers/*/config.v2.json`) with the new path as well to the new location. I used `perl` but one can use `sed` or whatever is your favourite utility to search and replace within multiple files. Then docker saw the moved images in the new location.

The complete process (adapted) looks like the follows:

```
(optional if you use compose)
sudo docker compose stop

sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
sudo systemctl stop containerd

sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json
(add/create the below lines in daemon.json)

{
    "data-root": "/mnt/sd/var/lib/docker"
}

sudo mv -f /var/lib/docker /mnt/sd/var/lib/
(the destination directory must exist)

sudo perl -pi -e 's%/var/lib/docker%/mnt/sd/var/lib/docker%g' `find /mnt/sd/var/lib/docker -name "config.v2.json"`
(update all config.v2.json files in moved images)

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start containerd
sudo systemctl start docker.socket
sudo systemctl start docker

sudo docker images
(should show moved images)

sudo docker compose up -d
(optional)
```